# Laravel - use dynamic parameter type in a method

Tags: laravel

I have following method inside **Controller**:

```
/**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     * @param SkillForm|null $model
     * @return Renderable
     */
    public function form(?SkillForm $model): Renderable
    {
        return view('components.forms.index', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Is it possible for a type (**SkillForm**) to be set somewhere else as a static variable, and use that? For example (this doesn't work):

```
/**
         * Show the form for creating a new resource.
         * @param SkillForm|null $model
         * @return Renderable
         */
        public function form(?self::model $model): Renderable
        {
            return view('components.forms.index', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
```

Comment: 100% use an interface, this is what they were designed for...

Answer (score 2):

Dynamically defining the type of a method is not supported by PHP at the moment.

If your goal is to validate that it is the right type, there are a few options available

1. Use a common interface

   ```php
   <?php

   interface A {}

   class B implements A {}
   class C implements A {}

   function foo(A $a) {}
   ```

   You could also use a Base class instead of interface, but usually interface
   is the preferred method.
2. Use type union

   ```php
   <?php

   function foo(A|B $a) {}
   ```
3. Perform the check inside the function

   ```php
   <?php

   class A
   {
       public static $model = 'SomeClass';

       public function foo($a)
       {
           throw_unless($a instanceof self::$model, Exception::class, "a is not an instance of " . self::$model);
       }
   }
   ```

The interface and union-type checks are usually better for IDE support and static analysis

Answer (score 0):

> Short answer is **PHP does not support dynamic typing for method parameters at runtime.**

You can **remove the type hint from the method signature and check the object type inside your method.**

```
/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @param mixed $model
 * @return Renderable
 */
public function form($model): Renderable
{
    if ($model instanceof SkillForm) {
        // handle SkillForm
    } elseif ($model instanceof AnotherForm) {
        // handle AnotherForm
    }
    
    return view('components.forms.index', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```